# Google Maps image not working in IE10 whereas chrome does

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-10, html2canvas

I was trying to use html2canvas to capture the image of the google map. Which it is being captured in chrome was okay where as internet explorer does not able to. appreciate  anyone who can help me with it. i have been solving for days,

below are the code:

```
function magic() {
    var target = $('#map');

    // if this is ie or other browser
    if (isIE()) {
        // is IE
        html2canvas(target, {
            useCORS: true,
            logging: true, 
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("#img").attr("src", data);

                var justTheData = data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");//Removes everything up to ...'base64,'
                document.getElementById("myImage").src="data:image/jpeg;base64," + justTheData;


            }
        });

    } else {
        // Other browser
        html2canvas(target, {
            useCORS: true,
            logging: true, 
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("#img").attr("src", data);
                window.open(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<img id="myImage" src="">
```

logging error for internet explorer

```
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images 
 html2canvas: Preload: Done. 
 html2canvas: start: images: 1 / 1 (failed: 0) 
 Finished loading images: # 1 (failed: 0)
```

logging error for chrome

```
Finished loading images: # 25 (failed: 0)
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this problem?

Comment: anyone solved this issue?

Comment: No. nobody had solve it. Thanks a lot

Comment: it's working on IE11, Edge....not IE10...IE9...so sad...